# I get a different output from what I expect from the following task

Tags: php, switch-statement, conditional-statements

When I use 0 for input, it outputs me this Between 100 and 200. With other values it works fine. Can someone explain me why this is happening?

http://prntscr.com/n7fzcy

```
<?php

$num = intval(readline());

switch ($num) {
    case $num < 100:
        echo "Less than 100";
        break;
    case $num >= 100 && $num <= 200:
        echo "Between 100 and 200";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Greater than 200";
}
```

Comment: You can't use logical operators  <,>,!=,=,== .... in case statements

Comment: You need to use `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use any logical operators <,>,!=,=,== .... in [switch case](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements.

Use a simple `if else` condition:

```
   $num = intval(readline());

    if($num < 100){
        echo "Less than 100";
    }else if($num >= 100 && $num <= 200){
        echo "Between 100 and 200";
    }else{
        echo "Greater than 200";
    }
```